# How to find two complex functions F and G, such that $F''(z)+G''(\bar{z})=0$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $z,\bar{z}$ be the complex variable and its conjugate respectively. If $F$ and $G$ are two complex functions, such that $F''(z) + G''(\bar{z})=0$

(a) Are there solutions for $F$ and $G$, other than $F(z)= a z^2+ b_1 z +b_2$ and $G(\bar{z})= -a \bar{z}^2 + c_1 \bar{z} + c_2$ ?

(b) Is there a general method to solve such ODE's in complex variables?

Comment: Your function $G$ in a) is not differentiable.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy If I define $F(z) = a z^2 + b_1 z + b_2$ and $G(z) = - a z^2 + c_1z + c_2$, $F$ and $G$ are both differentiable and satisfying $F''(z) + G''(\bar{z}) =0$, right? What am I missing here?

Comment: $\frac{d^2 F}{d z^2} = 2 a$;

$\frac{d^2 G}{d \bar{z}^2} = \frac{d^2 G}{d z^2}\bigg|_{z =\bar{z}} = -2 a$;



$F''(z) + G''(\bar{z}) = 2 a -2a = 0$. 


How is analyticity an issue here?

Comment: Mathematica is giving me quadratic in $z$, $F$ and $G$ as solutions.

Comment: I am sorry. You have obtained  a valid solution. In my answer (edited just now) I have proved that there are no other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is correct. Let me show that there are no other solutions.

If you are assuming differentiability for all $z$ then  $F$ and $G$ are entire functions. The fact that $F''=-G''$ on the real axis implies that $F''(z)=-G''(z)$ for all $z$. So you can obtain a solution pair $(F,G)$ by staring with a $G$ and taking $F(z)=G(z)+az+b$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants provided we also have $G''(z)=G''(\overline {z})$. But this last condition implies that $G''$ is a constant, so $g$ is a quadratic polynomial.

So the solution you have obtained is the most general solution.

Comment: The OP stated $F''(z) + G''(\overline{z})$, not $G''(z)$.

Comment: This argument also works in any open connected subset of $\mathbb C$ as long as it contains some segment of the real axis.

Answer (score 0):

The only analytic functions $f$ such that $f(\overline{z})$ is analytic, i.e. functions that are both analytic and conjugate-analytic, are constant.